# select div based on min and max value from data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to display div having data-price attribute, on checkbox select which contains diff range.

i knw how to get values from checkbox and how to work with data attribute but here, every div has data-price and need to show div having data-price from one of the selected range.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.h > .a1').hide();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.h > .a1[data-ftype=' + $(this).data("ftype")+ ']').show();
            $('.h > .a1[data-shape=' + $(this).data("shape")+ ']').show();

            //here i need price filter


        });
    } else {
        $('.h > .a1').show();

    }
  });
```

```
<input class="filter" data-ftype="full" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">ftype full
<input class="filter" data-ftype="half" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">ftype half
<input class="filter" data-ftype="without" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">ftype without

<input class="filter" data-shape="round" type="checkbox" id="checkbox4">round
<input class="filter" data-shape="cateye"type="checkbox" id="checkbox5">cateye
<input class="filter" data-shape="square" type="checkbox" id="checkbox6">sqaure

<input class="filter" data-min="1000" data-max="2000" type="checkbox" id="checkbox13">price1
<input class="filter" data-min="3000" data-max="4000" type="checkbox" id="checkbox13">price2
 <input class="filter" data-min="5000" data-max="10000" type="checkbox" id="checkbox13">price3


<div class="h"> 
<div class="a1" data-shape="round" data-ftype="full"  data-price="1500" >a1</div>
<div class="a1" data-shape="cateye" data-ftype="half" data-price="4000" >a2</div>
<div class="a1" data-shape="round" data-ftype="without" data-price="1000" >a3</div>
<div class="a1" data-shape="square" data-ftype="full" data-price="3500" >a4</div>
<div class="a1" data-shape="round" data-ftype="half" data-price="2500" >a5
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in selector to compare values with "greater than" and "lower than". You'll need to filter the elements manually depending on which checkboxes are checked.

Here's a working demonstration. First we hide all the divs using [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/), then we use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to decide which ones to [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/). Inside the filter callback, we return the result of [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which makes sure that at least one of the elements we iterate through meets the condition returned in the callback. ([`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/), when called without a specific index, simply converts the jQuery collection to an array of elements that we can use `.some()` on).

I also added an `else` statement to show all the divs when all checkboxes are unchecked.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  var checkedRanges = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  if (checkedRanges.length) {
    $(".h > .a1[data-price]").hide().filter(function() {
      $div = $(this);
      var divPrice = parseFloat($(this).data("price"))
      return checkedRanges.get().some(function(cb) {
        var minprice = parseFloat($(cb).data("min"));
        var maxprice = parseFloat($(cb).data('max'));
        return divPrice >= minprice && divPrice <= maxprice;
      });
    }).show();


  } else {
     $(".h > .a1[data-price]").show()
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1000 - 2000: <input class="filter" data-min="1000" data-max="2000" type="checkbox" id="checkbox13">
3000 - 4000: <input class="filter" data-min="3000" data-max="4000" type="checkbox" id="checkbox13">
5000 - 10000: <input class="filter" data-min="5000" data-max="10000" type="checkbox" id="checkbox13">
</p>
<div class="h">
  <div class="a1" data-price="1500">1500</div>
  <div class="a1" data-price="4000">4000</div>
  <div class="a1" data-price="1000">1000</div>
  <div class="a1" data-price="3500">3500</div>
  <div class="a1" data-price="2500">2500</div>
</div>
```